# How to export long number as string in csv file using php

Tags: php, export-to-csv, jackson-dataformat-csv

When I am trying to export all fields are okay except NID field. This numbers length is 17+ so, how can I show all the numbers in this field(nid)?? I have

[image: Here is the example of excel]

```
<?php

$filename = "hello.csv";
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_users";
$result_users = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$result_users->execute();
// Create array
$list = array ();

// Append results to array
array_push($list, array("## START OF May TABLE ##"));
while ($row = $result_users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($list, array_values($row));
}
array_push($list, array("## END OF May TABLE ##"));

// Output array into CSV file
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, ['Serial NO','English Name','Bangla Name','address','bn_address','user_no','nid','previous_cm','meter_no','type_of_user']);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
foreach ($list as $ferow) {
    fputcsv($fp, $ferow);
}
```

Comment: Try and convert that long number to string and try.

Comment: How to can I convert it when I am exporting it to CSV file? @BinitGhetiya

Comment: @ArafHossain What is the issue if it stays that way?

Comment: my client can't search NID in excel. And can't understand what is written in there. @vivek_23

Comment: @ArafHossain Ok,  what is the `datatype` of `NID` column in the database table?

Comment: You can see my code. I didn't select any datatype. I just call the database and then wanna print that's it. @vivek_23

Comment: @ArafHossain  $row = array_map(function($item){
    if(is_numeric($item)){
        return $item."";
    }
    return $item;
}, $row);

Comment: @ArafHossain please add in your while loop before array push.

Comment: @ArafHossain Yeah, but I am asking how is it stored in the database? It seems like the datatype is `BIGINT`. When you retrieve from DB and assign it to a PHP variable, PHP has it now in floating point scientific notation. To avoid this, you need to convert this type to  string while retrieving from DB itself. So, afterwards when you assign to a PHP variable, it still stays as a string.

Comment: db datatype is VARCHAR @vivek_23

Comment: @ArafHossain Ok, so this needs more debugging as to where the conversion is actually happening. `var_dump(array_values($row));` inside while loop and see what is the format in which you are receiving.

Comment: @ArafHossain if you are getting it correct in PHP as well, I bet excel sheet is doing that conversion.